# Json jqGrid binding error

Tags: json, jqgrid

In my mvc code, I am converting datatable to json.
 Result of my json is in correct format but it's not populating my jqgrid.

**json result :**

```
"{\"total\":2,\"page\":1,\"records\":2,\"rows\":[{\"id\":1,\"cell\":[\"1\",\"TEST
 ACCOUNT\",\"TEST LOB\",\"TEST REPORT\"]}]}"
```

**Code :**

```
public string JsonForJqgrid(DataTable dt, int pageSize, int totalRecords, int page)
    {
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
        StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        jsonBuilder.Append("{");
        jsonBuilder.Append("\"total\":" + totalPages + ",\"page\":" + page + ",\"records\":" + (totalRecords) + ",\"rows\"");
        jsonBuilder.Append(":[");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            jsonBuilder.Append("{\"id\":" + (i+1) + ",\"cell\":[");
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                jsonBuilder.Append("\"");
                jsonBuilder.Append(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                jsonBuilder.Append("\",");
            }
            jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
            jsonBuilder.Append("]},");
        }
        jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
        jsonBuilder.Append("]");
        jsonBuilder.Append("}");
        return jsonBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

jqGrid :

```
$("#jqTable").jqGrid({
        // Ajax related configurations
        url: "Staffing/LOBStaffing",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        // Specify the column names
        colNames: ["ID", "Account", "Lob", "Report"],

        // Configure the columns
        colModel: [
            { name: "ID", index: "ID", width: 40, align: "center", key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: "Account", width: 150, align: "center" },
            { name: "Lob", width: 150, align: "center" },
            { name: "Report", width: 150, align: "center" }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "List Staffing Details"
        //gridview: true,
        //scrollOffset: 0
    });
```

Controller Action :

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult LOBStaffing()
    {
        string sJson = _staffing.JsonForJqgrid(_staffing.GetStaffing(), 1, 2, 1);

        return Json(sJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: It's better to pass and object to `Json()` method of controller. i suppose that you get string json in your grid.

Comment: I am actually working on a dynamic data. any suggestions on some work around in working with a dynamic data?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Btw, thanks for the reply. what i've done is, since i am returning string data, just need to add JsonReader: {...} in jqgrid code and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways that i use in projects is to populate data to this classes:

```
public class Row
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> cell { get; set; }

    public Row()
    {
        cell = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class JqgridData
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int records { get; set; }
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }

    public JqgridData()
    {
        rows = new List<Row>();
    }
}
```

Your method `JsonForJqgrid` should return `JqgridData` structure allows you to store dynamic data, becouse you can add as much strings in `Row` as you want. `Json()` method in controller serialize this class right way for `jqgrid`.

If you need to store there not only strings but `DataTime`, `Decimal` etc. `Types` you can try to use `dynamic` type in  `public List<string> cell` property. But i didn't check how it really works.